# How many ways are there to arrange pairs so that no two enemies are next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

The following is the question I can't seem to figure out:

At a conference for superheroes and supervillains, 5 pairs of heroes and villains are
giving a panel seated in a row. Of course, if anyone sits next to their archenemy,
complete chaos will break out and ruin the convention. How many ways can you
arrange the panelists so that the program proceeds smoothly?

I have thought about this and all I could come up with for an answer is (10choose5) times the derangement of 4 elements. However it seems that this question is more complicated than that. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I'd go by Inclusion-Exclusion.  Look at the total number of seatings, subtract all those in which a specified pair are seated next to each other.  Then add back those in which two specified pairs are seated next to each other.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your response. I'm just confused as to which pairs exactly I have to subtract off.

Comment: Where's the confusion?  Let's say the heroes are $A,B,C,D,E$ and the villains are $a,b,c,d,e$.  How many seatings have $A,a$ next to each other?  Well...either we have the block $Aa$ or $aA$.  Picking one there would be $9!$ ways to arrange the group, so we have $2\times 9!$.  As there are five unacceptable pairs, we must subtract $10!$ (which happens to cancel the total, though of course we subtracted far too many). Now you have to add back those seatings with two bad pairs, and so on.

Comment: I should note:  the standard version of this problem would add the constraint that we are alternating between good and bad guys.  Are you sure you didn't mean to add that?  With that constraint this is known as the [Menage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem).  To be sure, the traditional version also assumes a circular table.

Comment: You can obtain $\binom{10}{5}$ by typing \binom{10}{5} between dollar signs.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!

So the total number of seatings would be 10!. So would this be correct? $$10! - (2 x 9!) - (2^2 x 8!) - (2^3 x 7!) - (2^4 x 6!) - (2^5 x 5!)$$

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I don't understand that formula.  First of all, inclusion exclusion alternates signs. Secondly you need to count the possible arrangement of pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total number of arrangements = $10! = 3628800$

Number of arrangements with Hero A next to Villain A = $2\cdot9\cdot8! = 725760$ as there are nine places for a block of two in a row of 10 and the block can be either way round and then the remaining eight people can be arranged however.

Number of arrangements with Hero A next to Villain A and Hero B next to Villain B = $2^2\cdot2!\cdot(\sum_{i=0}^6 (7-i))\cdot6! = 2^2\cdot2!\cdot(7\cdot8)/2\cdot6! = 161280$ as let there be i people between the two pairs. This i can be between 0 and 7 and there are then 7-i places to put the two pairs. Then the pairs can be swapped over or either of their orders can be reversed and then the remaining 6 people can be put in any of the remaining 6 places.

Number of arrangements with pairs A,B and C next to each other = $2^3\cdot3!\cdot(\sum_{i=0}^4 (5-i)(i+1))\cdot4! = 2^3\cdot3!\cdot35\cdot4! = 40320$ as this time if we have i people (not including the second pair) between the first pair and last pair we have to decide whether to distribute these people before or after the second pair and there are i+1 ways of doing this.

Number of arrangements with pairs A,B,C and D next to each other = $2^4\cdot4!\cdot(3+(3\cdot2)+3+3)\cdot2! = 2^4\cdot4!\cdot15\cdot2! = 11520$ as there are now 4 cases. If the pairs are all next to each other (in a block of 8) the remianing 2 people can either be both to the left of the 8, both to the right of the 8 or 1 either side so there are 3 possibilities. If 1 of the remaining people is inside the pairs and 1 is outside then there are 
6 possibilities and if they are both inside there are 3 possibilities when they're next to each other and another 3 when they're not.

Number of arrangements with all pairs next to each other = $2^5\cdot5! = 3840$

Hence the total number of possibilities with no pairs next to each other (using inclusion-exclusion) = $3628800 - \binom{5}{1}\cdot725760 + \binom{5}{2}\cdot161280 - \binom{5}{3}\cdot40320 + \binom{5}{4}\cdot11520 - 3840 = 1263360$

Comment: Thank you so much! My final answer in this case is: $$ 10! - \binom{5}{1}(2 * 9!) + \binom{5}{2}(2^2 * 8!) - \binom{5}{3}(2^3 * 7!) + \binom{5}{4}(2^4 * 6!) - \binom{5}{5}(2^5 * 5!) $$

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I overcomplicated working out how many arrangements have a certain number of pairs, it's much easier like that.